# Create a collection of truly unique objects of custom type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using TypeScript for my Vue app and have a custom type I'm working with

```
type MyCustomType = {
    fooProperty: string,
    barProperty: string
    /* ... other fields ... */
};
```

This type holds a bunch of properties acting as a "composite key". So the combination of all properties must be unique.

---

**First approach:**

The first idea coming to my mind is to simply use a `Set<T>`

```
const set: Set<MyCustomType> = new Set<MyCustomType>();

set.add({ fooProperty: "a", barProperty: "b" });

console.log(set.has({ fooProperty: "a", barProperty: "b" })); // expected: true, actual: false
```

The problem is that this set is not able to compare the objects. So `{ fooProperty: "a", barProperty: "b" } === { fooProperty: "a", barProperty: "b" } // false` ( based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#same-value-zero_equality )

---

**Second approach:**

An internal `Map<string, T>` holding `T` as a stringified key might be a good idea

```
class TrulyUniqueSet<ElementType> {
    private readonly elements: Map<string, ElementType> = new Map<string, ElementType>();

    private elementToKey(element: ElementType): string {
        return JSON.stringify(element);
    }

    public get size(): number {
        return this.elements.size;
    }
 
    public add(element: ElementType): TrulyUniqueSet<ElementType> {
        const elementKey: string = this.elementToKey(element);
 
        this.elements.set(elementKey, element);
        
        return this;
    }

    public clear(): void {
        this.elements.clear();
    }
 
    public delete(element: ElementType): boolean {
        const elementKey: string = this.elementToKey(element);
 
        return this.elements.delete(elementKey);
    }
    
    public has(element: ElementType): boolean {
        const elementKey: string = this.elementToKey(element);
 
        return this.elements.has(elementKey);
    }
 
    public values(): IterableIterator<ElementType> {
        return this.elements.values();
    }

    public forEach(callbackfn: (element: ElementType) => void): void {
        return this.elements.forEach((element: ElementType) => callbackfn(element));
    }
}
```

but things might get buggy if the structure of an object changes

```
const set: TrulyUniqueSet<MyCustomType> = new TrulyUniqueSet<MyCustomType>();

set.add({ fooProperty: "a", barProperty: "b" });

console.log(set.has({ fooProperty: "a", barProperty: "b" })); // expected: true, actual: true

console.log(set.has({ barProperty: "b", fooProperty: "a" })); // expected: true, actual: false
```

obviously because of different JSON strings.

---

**Third approach:**

I tried to extend the `Set` by overriding the equality check

```
class MyCustomTypeCollection extends Set<MyCustomType> {
    private customTypesAreEqual(firstValue: MyCustomType, secondValue: MyCustomType): boolean {
        return firstValue.fooProperty === secondValue.fooProperty &&
               firstValue.barProperty=== secondValue.barProperty;
               /* add other equality checks here */
    }
    
    public add(value: MyCustomType): this {
        if (!this.has(value)) {
            super.add(value);    
        }
        
        return this;
    }
 
    public has(value: MyCustomType): boolean { // truly check for duplicates
        return Array
            .from(this)
            .some((currentValue: MyCustomType) => this.customTypesAreEqual(currentValue, value));
    }
 
    public delete(value: MyCustomType): boolean {
        const filteredValues: MyCustomType[] = Array
            .from(this)
            .filter((currentValue: MyCustomType) => !this.customTypesAreEqual(currentValue, value)); // remove the value from the collection
 
        if(filteredValues.length < this.size) { // "rebuild" the collection
            this.clear();
 
            filteredValues.forEach(this.add);
 
            return true;
        }
 
        return false;
    }
}
```

The usage works as expected

```
const set: MyCustomTypeCollection = new MyCustomTypeCollection();

set.add({ fooProperty: "a", barProperty: "b" });

console.log(set.has({ fooProperty: "a", barProperty: "b" })); // expected: true, actual: true

console.log(set.has({ barProperty: "b", fooProperty: "a" })); // expected: true, actual: true

set.delete({ fooProperty: "a", barProperty: "b" });

console.log(set.has({ fooProperty: "a", barProperty: "b" })); // expected: false, actual: false

console.log(set.has({ barProperty: "b", fooProperty: "a" })); // expected: false, actual: false
```

**but** the implementation looks very slow in terms of performance.

---

I think I will go with the third approach but do you have any suggestions, better ideas or code improvements?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not add primary keys on database table and do an INSERT IGNORE?

Comment: thanks for your comment, I updated my question :) This is a Vue app (frontend)

Comment: why not use a `Map<T,Set<T>>` with `foo` being the key for the map and `bar` in the set.

Comment: Eventually, there will be a record/tuple proposal, that would let you use composite data within sets. But you can only use immutable data (and it looks like you wanted mutability). Either way, you'd need a different solution for now, but if you're interested, [here's](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-record-tuple) the proposal.

Comment: @jdt I think the OP provided just an example, there might be many more props to consider

Comment: yes @Question3r is right. But do you guys have any improvements for my third approach implementation?

Comment: Set can hold and compare objects if you ask nicely. Objects are reference types in JS. So you shouldn't add an object literal but a reference to it. i.e. Do like `var obj1 = {foo: "this", bar: "that"};` then `mySet.add(obj1);`. Now if you check for `obj1` like `mySet.has(obj1);` you get true. If you have multiple sets you can simply put them into an array and refrence them individually like `myObjArray[n]` etc...